# Logging an uncaught exception in try finally block

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, logging

I'm trying to log uncaught exception using `sys.excepthook` and it's working fine except in the below case where I'm getting an exception in both the `try` block and the `finally` block and there it only logs the exception which happened in the `finally` block. Is there a mechanism to log both the exceptions?

```
import sys
import logging
import traceback

logging.basicConfig(filename='app_3.log', filemode='w')
#logging.warning('hello how')
def log_except_hook(*exc_info):
    text = "".join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))
    logging.error("Unhandled exception: %s", text)

sys.excepthook = log_except_hook
try:
    None()
finally:
    raise Exception
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? (It matters.)

Comment: Its python 2.7.16

Comment: Then you're screwed. Get Python 3 and you'll have something to work with.

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#motivation…